# Zygote Errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime

I am getting these errors in Android Studio (logcat) when apps are being run

```
06-05 22:59:03.664  23521-23521/com.policia E/Zygote﹕ Zygote:  error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
        at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:224)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:704)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anybody tell me what causes these errors and how to solve them?

Comment: You need to post more code, it's hard to tell from just the error. What code is causing the error?